# How to enable the super key when running linux in a virtual machine in OSX

Tags: linux, macos, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome, vmware-fusion

I'm running Linux inside VMware in OSX.

I want to use gnome-do. The shortcut key to call it is super+space.

But that doesn't work when running inside VMware on OSX.

How can I enable to super key to function normally inside this virtual machine?

Comment: How do you currently map your `⌘` key? The Super key should be mapped to the `Win` key from Linux. So basically `⌘` → `Win` should suffice.

Comment: The super key is the same. That's the problem. OSX will recognize it even when I'm trying to use it inside the VM.

Comment: OSX will consume `⌘`, you mean? Have you tried mapping e.g. `Ctrl` to `Win`? What do your current settings look like?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. I'm using a windows keyboard, and the win key is the same as the super key in OSX. I haven't tried mapping ctrl to win, because then what would I use for ctrl?

Comment: Ok, you nowhere mentioned that you used a Windows keyboard. Maybe add that detail to your question.

Answer (score 0):

VMware Fusion has an option to disable OS X related shortcuts (including e.g. `Cmd-Space` for changing the keyboard layout, or Spotlight) when in the VM:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking for "kali disable super key" but I suppose this applies to other linux vmware/virtualbox guests too, so I hope this helps.

In my case the solution was to set "**overview shortcut**" in **tweaks** to **Right super** .

That way I can use my (left) "command" key in my mac for copy/paste etc in the guest VM.

[image]

[image]